# What is the signature of Run method

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to know that what is the signature of the run method of thread in java?

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/thread_run.htm

I have seen this link but here it is written that run method dose not return any value or takes any value as an argument.

So what is the signature of run()?

Comment: There is something called JavaDoc, please check the signature there.

Comment: `I want to know that what is the signature of the run method of thread in java?`
What stopping you to see the source code ?

Comment: The signature is written right in the article you have linked. So what do you really want to know? Do you know what a method *signature* is?

Comment: Maybe the OP wants this:  "()V"...  Then again, maybe not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's defined in the [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface :

`public void run ();`

Comment: In a pure academic point of view, the signature of a function is its name and parameters only (and not the return type nor visibility)